# Como inserir um valor passado por parâmetro na query sql

Tags: mysql, node.js, sql-insert

Estou passando dois valores de um input para a função "Insert", os valores então chegando na função normalmente, estou dando print neles para confirmar, mas mesmo assim não consigo inserir os valores passados na tabela.

Não retorna nenhum erro, simplesmente não insere os valores.

```
insert(connection, email, password) {
    console.log(email)
    console.log(password)
    var sql = `INSERT INTO register (email, password) VALUES (${email}, ${password})`
    connection.query(sql, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            return ('Falha ao inserir dados!' + err)
        }
        console.log('Dados inseridos com sucesso!')
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Poderia tentar utilizando os bindings nativos do banco de dados?

O resultado seria:

```
var sql = `INSERT INTO register (email, password) VALUES (?, ?)`
    connection.query(sql, [email, password], function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            return ('Falha ao inserir dados!' + err)
        }
        console.log('Dados inseridos com sucesso!')
    })
```

Comment: Nossa, tava me matando e era tão simples, deu certinho, muito obrigado.